# Base URL not updating on internationalized Angular web app

Tags: angular, angularjs, internationalization

I have an internationalized Angular web app and just added new languages. Each of the new languages are set up the exact same way in my angular.json file and all of the languages files are linked correctly. When I switch languages on the web page, the base url for some of the new languages gets updated and the page reloads correctly, displaying texts in the selected language. But for German and Polish, the base url does not get updated. I have to log out first and log back in for these two languages to be applied.

I’m stuck on this issue. I have not been able to figure out why the difference in behaviour, especially since all of the languages are added and set up the exact same way.

Have you experienced this before? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Here is a snippet from my angular.json file

```
{
  “projects”: {
     “angular”: {
        “18n”: {
           “sourceLocale”: “en-US”,
           “locales”: {
              “en”: {
                 “translation”: “src/i18n/messages.en.xtb”
              },
              “nl”: {
                 “translation”: “src/i18n/messages.nl.xtb”
              },
              “de”: {
                 “translation”: “src/i18n/messages.de.xtb”
              },
              “pl”: {
                 “translation”: “src/i18n/messages.pl.xtb”
              }
           }
        },…
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I noticed you are using non-standard quotes. That might be part of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have updated the quotes in the code, but still no difference in the behaviour.

Comment: Well then, all I have to say is: Good question. Unfortunately, I don't have an answer.

Comment: I finally figured out what the problem was. There’s a custom method in the application that checks if a country code already exist in a path before updating the URL. It checks the pattern “/${countryCode}” instead of “/${countryCode}/“, so if the window location path contains any combination of the country code, the URL will not get updated.

Comment: Congratulations on finding the answer. I recommend posting a self-answer to this question to make the solution more visible to others.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening because there’s a custom method in the application that checks if a country code already exist in a path before updating the URL. It checks the pattern “/${countryCode}” instead of “/${countryCode}/“, so if the window location path contains any combination of the country code, the URL will not get updated.

Using the pattern below for the check fixed my issue.

```
`/${countryCode}/`
```